# How to hide Grid border

Tags: wpf, grid, border, visibility

I have a grid with some controls inside. I want to hide the grid border.

Are there any specific properties which can be used to hide the grid border in WPF?

Comment: Are you talking about the DataGrid not the Grid?

Comment: The grid doesn't have a border, in fact it doesn't have any visualization

Comment: I am talking about Grid not DataGrid.

Comment: I get this issue if I have nested Grid, I want to hide the border of inner grid<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
            <Button Content="Test Button" Margin="5"></Button>
        </Grid>
        
    </Grid>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set `DataGrid.BorderThickness` to `0`.

Comment: I want to hide the Grid border not DataGrid

Comment: This helped me for a DataGrid, however it doesn't answer the question. -1

Answer (score 6):

I know this is a bit late to add to the thread but incase anyone else stumbles on this question this worked for me:

```
<Grid ShowGridLines="False">
```

Answer (score 0):

I too had a similar problem of getting dotted border around a part(Grid) of user control, only when focus is being set to the Grid and solved the problem using;

```
void Grid_GotFocus (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    Grid.FocusVisualStyle = null;
}
```

Hope it helps someone :)

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to set the color of the border (BorderBrush) to transparent for the items in the grid.

```
<Grid x:Name="WindowGrid" Visibility="Collapsed">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Tree}" Grid.Column ="0" BorderBrush="Transparent"/>
    <syncfusion:SfTreeGrid Grid.Column="1" BorderThickness="0"/>

</Grid>
```

[Example with visible borders for the grid's elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnyp2.png)